# PHP works fine as a link but not when called from AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a page which calls a PHP through AJAX

1. Clicking "TEST 1" does nothing, but the Apache logs shows

> ::1 - - [24/Oct/2016:10:30:17 -0200] "POST
>   /Media_Database/Pages/_copyFile.php HTTP/1.1" 200 167
>   "http://localhost/Media_Database/Pages/menu.htm" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows
>   NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/53.0.2785.148 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/1.4.589.38"

... and Chrome developer tool shows

[image]

2. Clicking "TEST 2" shows the message from PHP ... But it is not what I want, since no parameter goes to PHP
3. The jquery lib is local and it is being loaded

### >> MY HTML

```
<script src="_jquery-11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#saveFavorites").click(function(){

       var mp3src = document.getElementById("mp3player").src;
       $.ajax({
           type: "post",
           url:"_copyFile.php",
           data: { "varPath" : mp3src },
       }).success(function(result){
           console.log('AJAX success');
       }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
           console.log('AJAX failed' + textStatus);
       });
    });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="saveFavorites"> TEST 1 </a>
<a href="_copyFile.php">        TEST 2 </a>
```

### >> MY PHP

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("CALL OK");</script>'; ?>
```

### >> MY ENVIRONMENT

Using Chrome as client and XAMPP

Comment: That's because there is no text output on the page. AJAX isn't receiving anything as the response.

Comment: Where is this: var mp3src = document.getElementById("mp3player").src;

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Add a check for your parameter, `if (!empty($_POST['varPath'])){`..

Comment: Your jQuery is listening for `$("#saveFavorites").click()` so only `TEST 1` is going to fire the AJAX request and output `AJAX success` in your console. `TEST 2` is nothing more than an anchor tag so your web browser is simply visiting that URL, not passing any parameters, and executing the `alert();` which you've coded. What in the bloody heck is so confusing about this?

Comment: OK, I did cut a lots fo things to make my question more clear ...
Akshay > Yes, I have a lot of code below this alert("CALL OK")

Comment: OK, I didn't make my qustion clear. Sorry
Akshay > Yes, I have more code below this alert "CALL OK"

Chris85 > Yes, I am checking if param POST is empty

MonkeyZeus> I did just that to test where is the problem (Conclusion, it is not on PHP code, since the message is showing up when I click the link)

Patrick Q> My question is ... it all points outs that the PHP is being triggered from AJAX, but since the test message doesn't show up, something is wrong in between